# Show hidden package on Pub

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I released a package that had its homepage pointing to a private github repo.

I made the repo public and re-released the package. `pub publish` reports success, but I cannot find it by searching for its name or in my list of packages. Is there something I can do?

Edit: Using it as a dependency in another project works successfully.

Comment: It might take a bit until it's indexed. If you know the package name you can navigate to it using `https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/my_package_name`

Comment: Okay. I originally uploaded it last night. It's never taken this long before.

Comment: Can you please add a comment withe the name of your package in https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dartlang-dart/issues/1658